# Why I can't use parametric constructor within a class?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, constructor, initialization

I am using [Eigen 3.3.7](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html) library in my code. I can create and fill a vector with data in my `main()` as follows:

```cpp
Vector3d H1(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
Vector3d H2 = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0};
Matrix3d D(3,2); // Matrix is only initialised
```

However, if I do the same within a class, I get the syntax error:

```cpp
class data {
    Vector3d H1(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);   //syntax error
    Vector3d H = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0}; //still works
    MatrixXd D(3,2);              //syntax error
};
```

**Question 1:**

Why can't I use the same syntax within the body of a class?

How can I define 3-by-2 matrix as an attribute of `data` with Eigen?

**Question 2:**

I understand that `H1(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)` version invokes parametric constructor, however, I don't know what happens under the `Vector3d H2 = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0};` line. So what in fact does? And why does it work in the second case?

Comment: N.B.: If you know at compile time that your matrix is 3x2, you can use `Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 2> D;` -- And `Matrix3d D(3,2);` should assert at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Q1, [default member initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) (since C++11) supports only braced-initializer and equal-sign initializer, but not parentheses initializer. So you can just

```
class data {
    Vector3d H1{0.0, 0.0, 1.0};
    Vector3d H2 = Vector3d(0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // or as you showed, Vector3d H2 = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0}
    MatrixXd D1{3, 2};
    MatrixXd D2 = MatrixXd(3, 2); // or MatrixXd D2 = {3,2};
};
```

For Q2, `Vector3d H2 = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0};` performs [copy-list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) (since C++11), whose effect depends on how `Vector3d` is implemented. (In this case it seems to be the same as `Vector3d H1(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)`, i.e. the appropriate constructor is invoked to initialize the object.)